# Save document to Cosmos db with json property name as the property name

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have these class members with json property names

```
public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pk")]
        public string Pk { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phoneNumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I save a document to cosmos db I want the document to have json property names as the property names instead of class property names. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is how I am saving a document -

```
public async Task<Result> CreateUser(User user)
        {
            user.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            try
            {
                var container = _client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);
                ItemResponse<User> createdUser = await container.CreateItemAsync<User>(
                    item: user,
                    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("user")
                );

                return new Result
                {
                    Status = (int)createdUser.StatusCode,
                    RequestCharge = createdUser.RequestCharge,
                    User = createdUser.Resource
                };
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex)
            {
                return new Result
                {
                    Status = (int)ex.StatusCode,
                    Error = ex.Message,
                };
            }
        }
```

This is what the user object gets passed as data which are class property names -
[image]

@Mark Brown-

This is what is written to the container -
[image]

Comment: Also, since your `JsonProperty` property names seem to be for camel casing and nothing else, would [How do I configure Cosmos DB .NET 3.0 SDK to serialize with camel case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56084282) work as an alternative?

Comment: @dbc, cosmos uses Newtonsoft, not System.Text.Json.

Comment: Can you show what is actually written into the container?

Comment: @MarkBrown - sorry, my mistake.  I saw [this comment on *Changing default CosmosSerializationOptions to camelCase causes an exception in CosmosDB SDK V4 #1193*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1193#issuecomment-637899353) and incorrectly assumed it had been ported over.

Comment: @MarkBrown I have added the snip of the document in the container.

Answer (score 0):

This code from this post helped [How do I configure Cosmos DB .NET 3.0 SDK to serialize with camel case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084282/how-do-i-configure-cosmos-db-net-3-0-sdk-to-serialize-with-camel-case)

```
_cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endPoint, masterKey, new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                }
            });
```