# Unable to find a constructor to use for type NuGet.Versioning.VersionRange

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a DtoClass and referenced VersionRange class from Nuget.Versioning :

DtoClass:

```
  public class DependencyDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("VersionRange")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(VersionRangeConverter))]
    public VersionRange VersionRange { get; set; }
}
```

I have implemented simple JsonConverter in order to use Object's value in string representation format on swagger UI.

[image]

JsonConverter :

```
public class VersionRangeConverter : JsonConverter<VersionRange>
{       
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, VersionRange value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
   
    public override VersionRange ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, VersionRange existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Requires.NotNull(serializer, nameof(JsonSerializer));

        VersionRange versionRange = null;

        var versionRangeObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        if (versionRangeObject is null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (versionRangeObject is string)
        {
            if (!VersionRange.TryParse(versionRangeObject.ToString(), out versionRange))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic ver = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(versionRangeObject.ToString());
                NuGetVersion maxVersion = versionRange.MaxVersion;
                NuGetVersion minVersion = versionRange.MinVersion;
                bool isMinInclusive = versionRange.IsMinInclusive;
                bool isMaxInclusive = versionRange.IsMaxInclusive;
                string originalString = versionRange.OriginalString;

                versionRange = new VersionRange(minVersion, isMinInclusive, maxVersion, isMaxInclusive, null, originalString);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return versionRange;
    }
}
```

I have created one more Dependency class but without JsonConverter attribute over VersionRange  property as I want to save whole Object to Cosmos DB. I have used automapper to map these two classes. This works fine and it gets saved in db as expected. see below.
Document in Cosmos DB :

```
"Dependencies": [
        {
            "Name": "string",
            "VersionRange": {
                "IsFloating": false,
                "Float": null,
                "OriginalString": "[1.0.0, 2.0.0)",
                "HasLowerBound": true,
                "HasUpperBound": true,
                "HasLowerAndUpperBounds": true,
                "IsMinInclusive": true,
                "IsMaxInclusive": false,
                "MaxVersion": "2.0.0",
                "MinVersion": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Now when i am trying to read response from cosmos db by casting it to a class which does not have JsonConverter attribute over a VersionRange property. I am getting error.
Code to write to cosmos and cast repose :

```
ResourceResponse<Document> response = await this.DocumentDbClient.WriteAsync(doc.Id, this.CollectionName, doc).ConfigureAwait(false);
DependencyDoc dependencyDoc= (DependencyDoc)(dynamic)response.Resource;
```

Exception:

```
  "Message": "Unable to find a constructor to use for type NuGet.Versioning.VersionRange. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Module.Dependencies[0].VersionRange.IsFloating', line 1, position 285.",
```

Comment: You have written a `JsonConverter`? Do you have the code example for `VersionRangeConverter`, too?

Comment: @Martin Updated question with JsonConverter

Comment: I see IsFloating is readOnly property in VersionRangeClass.

public bool IsFloating
        {
            get
            {
                if (Float != null)
                {
                    return Float.FloatBehavior != NuGetVersionFloatBehavior.None;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

Comment: The problem is that `VersionRange` has multiple parameterized constructors + no parameterless constructor, so Json.NET does not know how to construct it.  I tried to create a converter that serialized all properties + deserialized by parsing the `OriginalString`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/3QKPBf.  It worked for your case, but not for `VersionRange.All` which has no original string.  Writing a `ReadJson()` method that handles all possible variations of properties of `VersionRange` seems nontrivial, and maybe outside the scope of a single question.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your detailed response.  We always anyway going to get certain range values as VersionRanges so its ok if i ignore  VersionRange.All.

Does this mean i don't need a mapper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the [VersionRangeFactory](https://github.com/NuGetArchive/NuGet.Versioning/blob/master/src/NuGet.Versioning/VersionRangeFactory.cs)

```cs
public class VersionRangeConverter : JsonConverter<VersionRange>
{       
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, VersionRange value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
   
    public override VersionRange ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, VersionRange existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Deserialize as Dictionary to be able to access the values by key
        var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(reader);

        // Utilize the `VersionRangeFactory`

        // Add your validations here if key exists, value is string etc.
        // This is just for demo purpose
        // ... or use one of the other constructors from the factory to build the full object from the dictionary which is now in your hand.
        var versionRange = VersionRange.Parse(dict["OriginalString"] as string, dict["IsFloating"] == "true");

        return versionRange;
    }
}
```

Here is a small [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rax2Ug)

### Update

If you have `VersionRange` from response body as `string` you can also add a handling to your converter to support full deserialized object and string object.

```cs
public override VersionRange ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, VersionRange existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        VersionRange versionRange = null;
        
        try
        {
            var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(reader);
            if(dict != null)
            {
                versionRange = VersionRange.Parse(dict["OriginalString"] as string, dict["IsFloating"] == "true");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Handling if response body contains only the string version declaration
            var strValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
            {
                versionRange = VersionRange.Parse(strValue);
            }
        }
        
        return versionRange;
    }
```

Next [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8yuWjD)

Comment: Thanks for detailed response with working example. Does this mean I do not need this.
"I have created one more Dependency class but without JsonConverter attribute over VersionRange property as I want to save whole Object to Cosmos DB. I have used automapper to map these two classes"

Comment: IMO its just about json serialization and using the correct `VersionRange` constructor in the `ReadJson(...)` method I would go for validating the values and pass them to the constructor you need. No dependency to AutoMapper, no dependency to CosmosDB.

Comment: Dict logic will surely help but  Problem is i read VersionRange value in string format from request body and then if you try to De-Serialize with Dict it gives null.

Comment: Ah get it. Ok then I would recommend two model classes one for the request object reading just the string `public string VersionRange { get; set; }` and then map it f.e. via automapper to your `DependencyDto` by using the `VersionRangeFactory`

Comment: Yes that's a good solution. Thanks Martin for your time and detailed responses to question.

Comment: can you have a look at this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76863589/how-to-hide-exclude-property-from-swaggerresponse-model-not-request-but-respons