# How to hide/exclude property from SwaggerResponse Model? Not Request but Response

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

Following is the Class from which VersionRange property needs to be excluded from Swagger**Response**Model :

```
public class Dependency
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    [JsonConverter(typeof(VersionRangeConverter))]
    [SwaggerExclude]       
    public VersionRange VersionRange { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using Attribute with ISchemaFilter to exclude property from SwaggerResponse model but it did not work out.

```
 public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (schema?.Properties == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var properties = context?.Type?.GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() != null);

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>())
            {
                if (schema.Properties.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                {
                    schema.Properties.Remove(prop.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> I do not want to use protected, internal access specifiers as I want
> property to consider during Serialization and De-Serialization.

> [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore] Attribute do not have
> effect either.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you'll find the answer [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/1230#issuecomment-1402756216) and [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/1230#issuecomment-1402786224).
[Brhav](https://github.com/Brhav) implemented the `[SwaggerIgnore]` attribute for that.

Comment: @Dennis Kiryanov Let me check. Thanks !

Comment: Please do not post [link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). At least provide some summary, quotes and if possible - code.